# Como puedo armar una Tabla HTML con el contenido de Arrays?

Tags: php, array, foreach

Hola estoy tratando de hacer una function() php en la que se ingrese un array y genere de salida una variable que contenga una tabla HTML con el contenido de los Arrays

[ ARRAY ]

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tipo] =>  Ahorros
            [code] =>  0730151719
            [simbolo] =>  $
            [total] =>  22.468
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tipo] =>  Sueldo
            [code] =>  1511981973
            [simbolo] =>  U$S
            [total] =>  689,44
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tipo] =>  Gastos
            [code] =>  1520131948
            [simbolo] =>  $
            [total] =>  685.965,81
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tipo] =>  Servicios
            [cuenta] =>  1940334931
            [simbolo] =>  U$S
            [total] =>  38.237,83
        )

)
```

[PHP]

> Hice el intento pero no me anida bien las < td >

```
function formateHTML($array){
    $table = false; $tr = false; $td = false; 
    foreach ($array as $saldo) {
        foreach ($saldo as $key => $value) {
            $td .= "$value";
        }
        $tr .= "$td";
    }
    $table = $tr;
    return "$table";
}
```

[ HTML ]

> Esta es la estructura que deseo que salga despues de hacer el arreglo.
>
> ```html
> <table border="1" style="width:100%;text-align:center;border:groove #243f00">
>   <tbody>
>     <tr>
>       <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
>       <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
>       <th scope="col">Moneda</th>
>       <th scope="col">Total</th>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>       <td>AHORROS</td>
>       <td>0180112760</td>
>       <td>$</td>
>       <td>7.962,97</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>       <td>SUELDO</td>
>       <td>0430170360</td>
>       <td>U$S</td>
>       <td>1.112,42</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>       <td>GASTOS</td>
>       <td>0653455657</td>
>       <td>$</td>
>       <td>768762,72</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>       <td>SERVICIOS</td>
>       <td>0764353456</td>
>       <td>U$S</td>
>       <td>456.362</td>
>     </tr>    
>   </tbody>
> </table>
> ```

Comment: Hola @Paolo, bienvenida a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function formateHTML($array){
    $title = ''; $tab = '';
    foreach ($array as $i => $tr) {
        $tab.= '<tr>';
        foreach ($tr as $key => $value) {
            if($i==0) $title.= '<th scope="col">'.$key.'</td>';
            $tab.= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
        $tab.= '</tr>';
    }
    $table = '<table border="1">';
    $table.= '<tr>'.$title.'</tr>';
    $table.= $tab;
    $table.= '</table>';
    return $table;
}
```